# Deployment in Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

i have a project in svn.
I have linked it to jenkins.
I can complie it and test it.
I want to deploy it in the same repository but under a different branch.
I am trying to use the mvn deploy command.

Can you help me with it. 
Like I want to know how to use and implement this command.

Thanks

Comment: How does your current code and configuration look like? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, mvn deploy is used to deploy to the binary repo not to any branch, so your question is not clear.

Comment: Hi.. currently I have the code in my dev env. And after compiling and testing I want to move it to staging env. I am not sure how to accomplish this goal using maven commands. Any idea on it